# Sitefinity checkout widget: how to populate billing address with custom data

Tags: e-commerce, sitefinity

What sitefinity event do I wire into modify the default billing behavior of the checkout widget?  I have read over these pages

- https://docs.sitefinity.com/the-checkout-process
- https://docs.sitefinity.com/event-system-eventhub
- https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-list-of-events

I need to override this part of the checkout widget

> If the user is a returning customer the shipping address will appear prefilled with the information that was last specified by the user.

Will this do it for me?  https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-preprocessorder-event

update : per requested here is some code i have tried

wiring into the OnEcommerceCheckoutPageChanging Event
The global.ascx.cs
      private void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
     {
      EcommercePriceServiceCustomTiers.Register();

```
  if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
  {

    EventHub.Subscribe<IEcommerceCheckoutPageChangingEvent>(SitefinityWebApp.Custom.Ecommerce.EcommerceCheckoutPageChangingHandler.OnEcommerceCheckoutPageChanging);}
```

Here is the code to get the addresses.  this get it after the page loads i need the event before this happens

```
  public static void OnEcommerceCheckoutPageChanging(IEcommerceCheckoutPageChangingEvent evt)
    {
        // This event could be raised after the shopping cart was destroyed so make sure you return when the ShoppingCartId is empty or null.
        if (evt.ShoppingCartId == Guid.Empty || evt.ShoppingCartId == null)
        {
            log.Debug("The Cart no longer exists");
            return;
        }

         if(evt.CurrentStepIndex == 0)
        {
            var ordersManager = OrdersManager.GetManager();
            // Get a copy of the shopping cart order based on the evt.ShoppingCartId.
            var cartOrder = ordersManager.GetCartOrder(evt.ShoppingCartId);
            List<CartAddress> adds = cartOrder.Addresses.ToList();// new List<CartAddress>();
            foreach(CartAddress add in adds)
            {
               /// make the modifications to the addresses here
               /// this fires after i need it to , i need the event before this fires
            /// note the "evt.CurrentStepIndex == 0" step i am referencing
            }

            ordersManager.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Comment: @nixkuroi I updated the original message with the code that does execute but does so after i need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is default behavior of the checkout widget.  I just placed an order using the default setup of widgets, then went back a placed another order and my address is populated.

If you need to get to different page events you can attach a code behind to the user control.

In the widget template modify the first line to look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.Helpers.Checkout.CheckoutTabStrip" %>
```

The **inherits** is a class the implements UserControl.  The file is located in ~/{ProjectRoot}/Helpers/Checkout/CheckoutTabStrip.cs (can live wherever)

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace SitefinityWebApp.Helpers.Checkout
{
    public class CheckoutTabStrip : UserControl
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (FindControl("checkoutTabStrip") is RadTabStrip checkoutTabStrip)
            {
                checkoutTabStrip.DataBound += CheckoutTabStrip_DataBound;
            }
        }

        private void CheckoutTabStrip_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //DO STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the Rad Tab Strip docs for more information on events:
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/tabstrip/tabs/working-with-tabs-at-the-server